# Screen reader reading class names?

Tags: html, screen-readers

I was wondering if screen readers are reading classnames?

Example:

```
photo
description
price

<img src>    
<p class="description"> …
<p class="price"> …
```

Comment: Screenreaders generally do not read properly formatted CSS classes.

Comment: okay thank you a lot.
Can I add a tag that has some value for screenreaders en searchengines?

Comment: The alt tag in html will let you describe your DOM elements for screen readers.